# Doctrine ORM: Populate join column of related entities on persist

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

Given the below simple entities in Doctrine ORM, is there a simple way to create a `Parent` object, add `Children` to it, and then persist the Parent and its children in one call to `EntityManager#persist()` and `EntityManager#flush()`?

Currently, I'm persisting `Parent`, flushing the entity manager, then adding `Parent` to each `Child`, persisting each `Child` and then flushing the entity manager again. Otherwise, each `Child` is persisted to the database, but the join column is null. I tried a lifecycle callback on `Parent`, but `postPersist()` is called after all entities are persisted, not right after the parent entity and before the children are persisted.

```
class Parent {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(
   *    targetEntity="Child",
   *    mappedBy="parent",
   *    cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"}
   * )
   */
  protected $children;

  public function __construct () {
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection;
  }

  public function addChild (Child $child) {
    $this->children[] = $child
  }
}

class Child {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(
   *    targetEntity="Parent",
   *    inversedBy="children",
   * )
   */
  protected $parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to persist the children manually. That's what `cascade={"persist"}` is for.

Try this in `Parent`'s `addChild()`:

```
public function addChild (Child $child) {
    $this->children[] = $child;
    $child->setParent($this);
}
```

Now you can persist and flush only the parent and its children will be persisted too.

Comment: Aw, of course. That works a charm. Thanks muchly.

I'd've thunk setting the children would have been enough, but clearly not.

Comment: I think the reason it's not enough is that in the DB the relationship is completely described on the Child side, there's nothing about it in the Parent table.  So clearly you have to make a change to the Child table, which corresponds to persisting the Child Entity, which it's probably safer not to have happen by default if you persist the Parent.

Answer (score 0):

every time you use manytoone or onetomany relations, use 
    php app/console doctrine:generate:entities  
in the console, so it will autocreate the functions addChild and removeChild. This way you dont need to create them manually

Comment: I did, and the addChild() method did not include the call to $child->setParent()